# How to check MySQL connection state in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi I am connecting to MySQL in C# and I need to check is the SQL connection open or not. If open then do something or if not do something.
I am trying by below code but I am getting error.

```
var sqlCon= new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.sString);
var mySQLCon= new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dString);
sqlCon.Open();
mySQLCon.Open();
if (sqlCon.State==ConnectionState.Open && mySQLCon.State==ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(@"Connection working.");
  }
else
  {
    MessageBox.Show(@"Please check connection string");
  }
```

I am getting error on `mySQLCon.State==ConnectionState.Open`
Error is `InvalidOperationException`
How can we check the MySQL connection state.

Comment: If the Open call fails, I'd expect an exception to be thrown anyway...

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. I have updated my question.

Comment: It seems very strange that you get the exception on the line that checks the connection state. Looking at the sources there is nothing there that could throw an exception. It is more likely that you have a problem in the Open command

Comment: As a side note, you should always close/dispose unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think error should be in connection string. Check your connection string first.

if connection string is correct and there is some another issue try something like below.

```
var sqlCon= new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.sString);
var mySQLCon= new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dString);
sqlCon.Open();
mySQLCon.Open();
var temp = mySQLConn.State.ToString();
if (sqlCon.State==ConnectionState.Open && temp=="Open")
 {
   MessageBox.Show(@"Connection working.");
 }
else
 {
  MessageBox.Show(@"Please check connection string");
 }
```

And one more thing as @Leri mentioned you should always close/dispose unmanaged resources.
Hope it work for you.

Comment: Yes sir. I think there was problem in unmanaged resources. I have restarted the system and it worked. Thank you so much.