# How to Check connection status at run time using C#.net (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have client server application (Lan base). Initially the client application successfully connects to server but later at run time the connection is being lost due to some reason (e.g server machine shutdown ). This is triggering an error something like `UNABLE TO CONNECT TO HOST`. How can i check the status of connection at run time?

The code is as follows

Connection class

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;  
namespace Connection_Checker
{
 public class Connection
 {
   public static MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=arc;User Id=root;Password=root;");
 }
}
```

Form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Connection.cnn.Open();
}

//and timer
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Connection.cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    this.Text = "Connected";
  }
  else
  {
    this.Text = "Disconnected";
    return; 
  }
}
```

my timer is enable = true

Comment: Don't leave your connections open like that.  Open it, get your data, close it.  Is your question about the timer?  What is it displaying?

Comment: My goal is during runtime and connection is lost the system will say Disconnected and I implement that using timer . . .

Comment: Just use a Try...Catch around your data calls if you expect your data connections to be that flaky.

Comment: And what is your question? You need to explain _specifically_ what happens, and how that's different from what you want to happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sir Shadow and answer? by the way thanks..

Comment: Don't do that. When you need a connection: open it, use it, close it.

Comment: my Question is almost the same with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785220/how-to-check-mysql-connection-state-in-c-sharp....But Mine my goal is I want to Check the status of connection at  RUNTIME . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you in the form I would not open the connection in form load event.

Instead my method where I would be fetching the data would be something like this

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;  
namespace Connection_Checker
{
 public class Connection
 {
     public static connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=arc;User Id=root;Password=root;";
 }
}
```

In the form

```
private void GetData()
{
 try{
     using (MySqlSqlConnection connection = new MySqlSqlConnection(Connection.connectionString ))
     {
       connection.Open();
       //GetData
        connection.Close();
      }
 }
 catch
 {
     MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to fetch Data");
 }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //I would avoid this. 
  // Connection.cnn.Open();
}

//I am not sure why you are having this.
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //if (Connection.cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
  //{
  //  this.Text = "Connected";
  //}
  //else
  //{
  //  this.Text = "Disconnected";
  //  return; 
  //}
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume the exception is always a connection error unless you inspect the exception error itself.

Comment: You saved my day sir shadow . . .Thank you so much . . my problem solved . . .This is my first time to ask here and got solved just for a couple of minutes . ..

Answer (score 0):

Catching transmit errors does not tell you when the connection fails. It only tells you that the connection was not available when you tried to use it.

For continuous presence-monitoring using a timer as per your example, use this extension method to directly query the TCP connection state.

```
public static class Extensions
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Obtain the current state of the socket underpinning a TcpClient.
  /// Unlike TcpClient.Connected this is reliable and does not require 
  /// capture of an exception resulting from a failed socket write.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="tcpClient">TcpClient instance</param>
  /// <returns>Current state of the TcpClient.Client socket</returns>
  public static TcpState GetState(this TcpClient tcpClient)
  {
    var foo = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()
      .SingleOrDefault(x => x.LocalEndPoint.Equals(tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint));
    return foo != null ? foo.State : TcpState.Unknown;
  }
}
```

However, as already mentioned by others in comments, your dependence on continuous connection probably reflects serious design flaws in your application. You should heed the advice you have been given and redesign your app. Hogging connections seriously limits scalability, and will not make you popular with your network administrator or your database administrator.